JavaScript fetch() Syntax Error: "missing ) after argument list"
I'm encountering a missing ) after argument list error in my JavaScript code when trying to use the fetch() function to retrieve JSON data. Despite thorough review, I can't pinpoint the source of the issue. Here's the relevant code snippet:
fetch(myString)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    initializeChat(data.chatMessages);
  })
  .catch(error => console.error("Failed to load chat messages:", error));


the code snippet you posted looks valid - the error is elsewhere in code you haven't shown

The error was pointed at lines 2 to 7 which was this part

It's probably caused by the surrounding code. The posted code is correct.

pointed at lines 2 to 7 I've never seen an error "pointing" to a range of lines

Paste full code
